# Swift application quits after open, works from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am encountering a strange situation with a simple application I develop. When I deploy the application using Xcode (with debugger attached), it works perfectly.

When I close Xcode, disconnect the phone, kill and restart the application, it works just fine, too! For several hours that is.

After some time (usually the next day morning) when I try to open the app up, it immediately fails. A white rectangle filling the screen animation does happen, but when the application is supposed to flash its UI in, it quits instead.

How can I get ahold of the crash logs from the iPhone? Does it store any? This application is not from the AppStore, it's my development application installed through Xcode.

When I re-deploy it after finding this has happened again, hoping I'll get something with a debugger attached, it starts working again. This has happened to two of my apps.

Comment: You could try to look into your device's logs: Window->Devices -> Select your device-> Click 'View Device Logs'. Find your app crash there and on the right  side you should see a crash report.

Comment: @NikitaGaydukov That's the answer, can you answerize your comment so I can accept it?

Comment: sure, added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to look into your device's logs: Window->Devices -> Select your device-> Click 'View Device Logs'. Find your app crash there and on the right side you should see a crash report.